# How to correctly rotate 2D orthographic projection around a central point?

Tags: matrix, projection, projection-matrix, rust

I want to rotate a 2D orthographic projection around the centre point of my view. However, something is off (it looks like a translation) but I'm not sure what.

To put some concrete values on the variables below:

- rotation = 90.0 degrees
- zoom = 0.5
- size = (640, 480)
- center = (320, 340)

My code is as follows:

```
Transform::orthographic(0.0, self.size.x / self.zoom, 0.0, self.size.y / self.zoom, 0.0, 1.0) * Transform::from_trs(self.center, -self.rotation, Vec2f::ONE, self.center)
```

And the values from the transform matrix (columnar):

```
[-0.00000000006829905, 0.0015625,          0, -1.03125,
0.0020833334,          0.0000000000910654, 0, -0.37500012,
0,                     0,                  1,  0,
0,                     0,                  0,  1]
```

Here's the correct rotation and the code (borrowed from SFML and re-written in Rust for my own transform class):

```
let angle = self.rotation.as_radians();
let cosine = angle.cos();
let sine = angle.sin();
let tx = -self.center.x * cosine - self.center.y * sine + self.center.x;
let ty = self.center.x * sine - self.center.y * cosine + self.center.y;

let a = 2.0 / (self.size.x / self.zoom);
let b = -2.0 / (self.size.y / self.zoom);
let c = -a * self.center.x;
let d = -b * self.center.y;

Transform::new(
        a * cosine, a * sine,   0.0, a * tx + c,
       -b * sine,   b * cosine, 0.0, b * ty + d,
        0.0,        0.0,        1.0, 0.0,
        0.0,        0.0,        0.0, 1.0,
)
```

And the values from the transform matrix:

```
[-0.00000000006829905, 0.0015625,          0, -0.53125,
0.0020833334,          0.0000000000910654, 0, -0.66666675,
0,                     0,                  1,  0,
0,                     0,                  0,  1]
```

Having done the calculations by hand, the difference for the translation in x is the value of `-c` from the correct implementation, but I don't know why this is negated in comparison. I have no idea where the difference for the translation in y comes from.

What the incorrect rotation looks like:

[image]

And the correct rotation:

[image]

FWIW, here is the code for the `Transform` class:

```
impl Transform {
    pub const fn new(
        m00: f32, m01: f32, m02: f32, m03: f32,
        m10: f32, m11: f32, m12: f32, m13: f32,
        m20: f32, m21: f32, m22: f32, m23: f32,
        m30: f32, m31: f32, m32: f32, m33: f32,
    ) -> Self {
        Self {
            matrix: [
                m00, m10, m20, m30,
                m01, m11, m21, m31,
                m02, m12, m22, m32,
                m03, m13, m23, m33,
            ]
        }
    }

    pub fn from_trs<V, A>(position: V, rotation: A, scale: V, origin: V) -> Self
    where
        V: Into<Vec2f>,
        A: Into<Angle>,
    {
        let position = position.into();
        let rotation = rotation.into();
        let scale = scale.into();
        let origin = origin.into();

        let angle = -rotation.as_radians();
        let cosine = angle.cos();
        let sine = angle.sin();
        let sxc = scale.x * cosine;
        let syc = scale.y * cosine;
        let sxs = scale.x * sine;
        let sys = scale.y * sine;
        let tx = -origin.x * sxc - origin.y * sys + position.x;
        let ty = origin.x * sxs - origin.y * syc + position.y;

       Self::new(
            cosine, sine,   0.0, tx,
           -sine,   cosine, 0.0, ty,
            0.0,    0.0,    1.0, 0.0,
            0.0,    0.0,    0.0, 1.0,
       )
    }

    pub fn orthographic(left: f32, right: f32, top: f32, bottom: f32, near: f32, far: f32) -> Self {
        // note: depth is in range 0 to 1, not -1 to 1 like in OpenGL.
        let a = 2.0 / (right - left);
        let b = 2.0 / (top - bottom);
        let c = 1.0 / (far - near);
        let tx = (left + right) / (right - left);
        let ty = (top + bottom) / (top - bottom);
        let tz = near / (far - near);

        Self::new (
            a,   0.0, 0.0, -tx,
            0.0, b,   0.0, -ty,
            0.0, 0.0, c,   -tz,
            0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  1.0,
        )
    }
}

impl Mul for Transform {
    type Output = Transform;

    fn mul(self, rhs: Self) -> Self::Output {
        let r0 = [self.matrix[0], self.matrix[4], self.matrix[8],  self.matrix[12]];
        let r1 = [self.matrix[1], self.matrix[5], self.matrix[9],  self.matrix[13]];
        let r2 = [self.matrix[2], self.matrix[6], self.matrix[10], self.matrix[14]];
        let r3 = [self.matrix[3], self.matrix[7], self.matrix[11], self.matrix[15]];

        let c0 = [rhs.matrix[0],  rhs.matrix[1],  rhs.matrix[2],  rhs.matrix[3]];
        let c1 = [rhs.matrix[4],  rhs.matrix[5],  rhs.matrix[6],  rhs.matrix[7]];
        let c2 = [rhs.matrix[8],  rhs.matrix[9],  rhs.matrix[10], rhs.matrix[11]];
        let c3 = [rhs.matrix[12], rhs.matrix[13], rhs.matrix[14], rhs.matrix[15]];

        Self::new(
            dot(&r0, &c0), dot(&r0, &c1), dot(&r0, &c2), dot(&r0, &c3),
            dot(&r1, &c0), dot(&r1, &c1), dot(&r1, &c2), dot(&r1, &c3),
            dot(&r2, &c0), dot(&r2, &c1), dot(&r2, &c2), dot(&r2, &c3),
            dot(&r3, &c0), dot(&r3, &c1), dot(&r3, &c2), dot(&r3, &c3),
        )
    }
}

fn dot(u: &[f32; 4], v: &[f32; 4]) -> f32 {
    u[0] * v[0] + u[1] * v[1] + u[2] * v[2] + u[3] * v[3]
}
```

Why does this extra translation exist in the working implementation when I already account for moving the origin in my TRS matrix? And, how can I correctly calculate this translation and apply it to my transform?